# List placement on different devices flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

We have a list that we need to stay in the same place regardless of device screen size. whats the best way to achieve this? Its too high on smaller devices and in place on larger screens

Here is the list code

```
 Widget _listNews() {
return AnimatedPositioned(

  curve: Curves.linear,
  bottom: isViewAll ? 0 : 0 + viewAllHeight,
  left: 20,
  right: 20,
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
  child: AnimatedContainer(
    curve: Curves.linearToEaseOut,
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
    height: isViewAll ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 300 : 430,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
    child: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'Forum News',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: _getFontSize(20), fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text(
                  'View All',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: _getFontSize(18), color: Colors.blue),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    isViewAll = !isViewAll;
                    viewAllHeight = isViewAll ? 290 : 0;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ]),
        _getNewsTile('lib/img/profile.jpg'),
        Divider(),
        _getNewsTile('assets/images/KC_logo.png'),
        Divider(),
        _getNewsTile('assets/images/pokimon_3.png'),
        Divider(),
        _getNewsTile('assets/images/pokimon_4.png'),
        Divider(),
        _getNewsTile('assets/images/pokimon_5.png'),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

### Get News List Code

```
 Widget _getNewsTile(String image) {
return ListTile(
    title: Text(
      'Concussions May Stunt Recovery from Sleep Deprivation',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: _getFontSize(16), fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
    ),
    subtitle: Text('July 10',style: TextStyle(fontSize: _getFontSize(16)),),
    trailing: Image.asset(
      image,
    ));
 }
```

It moves vertically on different devices and is out of place

Comment: Same place relative to what? A particular corner? The center? Another widget?

Comment: Bottom of a container

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Align`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html) widget to align things relative to its parent container. There are nine preset alignments you can choose from, or you can create a custom alignment with some fine-tuning and trial-and-error. Judging from your requirements, you'll want to pass it `Alignment.bottomCenter`.

```dart
Container(
  ...
  child: Align(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
    child: ...
  ),
),
```